# Can a bool variable store more than 0x01?

Tags: c++, binary, boolean, shift

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool a = 0x03;
    bitset<8> x(a);
    cout<<x<<endl;

    a = a>>1;
    bitset<8> y(a);
    cout<<y<<endl; 
}
```

The result is:

```
00000001    
00000000
```

The result is **not**:

```
00000011
00000001
```

If I change the type of `a` from `bool` to `char`, the result will be the second one.
It means that I cannot store more than 0x01 in a `bool`, all right value greater than 0x01 are treat as 0x01.

All compiler has the behavior?

Comment: Try `bool a = 2;`. Same thing happens.

Answer (score 9):

§4.12 Boolean conversions [conv.bool]

> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. **A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false**; **any other value is converted to true**. A prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be converted to a prvalue of type bool; the resulting value is false.

Answer (score 7):

The only values you can *legitimately* store in a `bool` object are `false` and `true`. All conversions from other types to `bool` yield one of those two values. A `bool` object is always at least 8 bits in size (unless it's a bit field), but the language deliberately makes it difficult to store any of the other 254 (or more) possible values.

You *can* play tricks, like using `memcpy`, or using a union, or using pointer conversions, to store any other value that will fit. But if you do so, it *probably* makes your program's behavior undefined. What that means is that the compiler is permitted to generate code that *assumes* the stored value is either `false` or `true` (or `0` or `1`). Store something else, and your program's behavior is unpredictable.

`bool` is at least 8 bits because the C++ memory model doesn't deal well with sub-byte objects (other than bit fields). You're not supposed to use those other 7 (or more) bits.

If you want to store more than 2 values in an object, don't make it a `bool`.

Answer (score 4):

`bool a = 0x03;` converts 0x03 to a boolean value. Since every numeric value that is not zero will be evaluated to be true, you'll see the first result, regardless of which data you'll assign.

Answer (score 2):

C++11, §3.9.1/6:

> Values of type bool are either true or false. [...]

Answer (score 1):

A `bool` can only hold two values: `false` and `true`.

When/if used in an integer context, a `bool` can be converted to an `int`. In this case, `false` converts to `0` and `true` converts to `1`.

Regardless of the size of storage used for a `bool` (e.g., `sizeof(bool)==1` and `sizeof(bool)==4` are both fairly common) it can still only hold the two values `false` and `true`, which always convert to `0` and `1` respectively. No other value is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you even think you could?
It's like saying `int i = "abc";`.

Comment: A bool has 1 byte memory size, so I think I can assign a 1 byte value to it. "abc" is a char array, it doesn't make sense to put "abc" in an int.

Comment: @user2261693 The compiler will always convert your expression to a boolean value first, before storing in memory. If you really want to store something else in that byte, you could do `reinterpret_cast<char&>(a) = 3`, but be aware that that's undefined behaviour and compilers can optimise it into something you weren't expecting.